# Install wheel from a directory using Poetry

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging, python-poetry

I am using a python package which has a complex build process, and hence it provides wheels for various platforms.

I am looking for a way to configurate `poetry` to be able to install the package using the right wheel (for each platform it will be ran on) given a path to a directory containing the wheels

This is possible with pip by using

```
pip install --no-index --find-links /path/to/wheels/ package_name
```

Note:
Hacks are also welcome (e.g - wrapping the wheels in another python package / running code in some `setup.py`)

Comment: _"given a path to a directory containing the wheels"_ Poetry supports the [Simple Repository API](https://peps.python.org/pep-0503/) out of the box. See [Repositories](https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories/). It works exactly the same as in pip.

Comment: @Brian61354270, that would require uploading the directory and serving it through some HTTP server right? (i also heard about using S3 or alike for that)

Anyway - i am looking for a local solution

Comment: No, it does not. URL doesn't mean HTTP. A local file path like `file:///path/to/wheels/` is a URL. Both poetry and pip support `file://` URLs (that's why the command in your question works, the `file://` is implicit for local directories passed to `--find-links`).

Comment: @Brian61354270 could you get that to work?
when using `package = {path = 'file:///path/to/wheels'}` poetry errors and says that the path doesn't exist, when changing the type from path to url, it errors and says the it "does not seem like a valid url".

tried adding a poetry source  - https://python-poetry.org/docs/master/repositories/#simple-api-repository
however when configuring the url of the source, it seems that file urls are not supported
"No connection adapters were found for 'file:///path/to/wheels"

Comment: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/5983

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, *Poetry* does not have a feature comparable to *pip*'s `--find-links`, as stated by this [open feature request](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/5983).

For such a use case, I would recommend to use [*simpleindex*](https://github.com/uranusjr/simpleindex).

Also note *Poetry*'s "[*Single Page Link Source*](https://python-poetry.org/docs/master/repositories/#single-page-link-source)" feature that might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pip` with `poetry` as they both can point to the same virtual environment.

```bash
poetry shell
pip install --no-index --find-links /path/to/wheels/ package_name
```

However you cannot make any of these installs permanent (part of `pyproject.toml`)

As a workaround you can make "post-install steps" with `pip` part of Github Actions, Makefile, or any other install recipe.